# How to switch between Java 8 and Java 11 in docker container

Tags: shell, java-8, scripting, dockerfile, java-11

I am using Dockerfile which installs two Java versions (Java 8 and Java 11). I want to set Java 11 as default version. As per the need it switch from Java 11 to Java 8. For this, I built Docker image from private base-image and installed both versions and provided environment for the Java 11 and I created a shell script which switches Java version from Java 11 to Java 8 during running container. This approach is failing. Please let me know any possibility to resolve this issue.

Dockerfile :

```sh
FROM private=base-image
ARG JAVA_VERSION=11.0.12.0
ARG JAVA_ARCHIVE_NAME=java-certified-jdk_x64_linux_11.0.12.0.bin
RUN curl {java-resource}/cloud/runtimes/java/${JAVA_VERSION}/linux/x86_64/${JAVA_ARCHIVE_NAME} -o /tmp/java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin && \
chmod +x /tmp/java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin &&\
echo "INSTALLER_UI=silent" > /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
echo "LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE" >> /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
echo "USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/java/java-certified-11-jdk" >> /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
/tmp/java-java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin -i silent -f /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
ln -sf /opt/java/java-certified-11-jdk/bin/* /usr/local/bin/  && \
rm /tmp/java-java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin && \
rm /tmp/java-installer.properties

ARG JAVA8_VERSION=8.0.6.35
ARG JAVA8_ARCHIVE_NAME=java-sdk-8.0-6.35-x86_64-archive.bin
RUN curl https://public.dhe.java.com/javadl/export/pub/systems/cloud/runtimes/java/${JAVA8_VERSION}/linux/x86_64/${JAVA8_ARCHIVE_NAME} -o /tmp/java-java-sdk-${JAVA8_VERSION}.bin && \
chmod +x /tmp/java-java-sdk-${JAVA8_VERSION}.bin &&\
echo "INSTALLER_UI=silent" > /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
echo "LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE" >> /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
echo "USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/java/java" >> /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
/tmp/java-sdk-${JAVA8_VERSION}.bin -i silent -f /tmp/java-installer.properties && \
rm /tmp/java-java-sdk-${JAVA8_VERSION}.bin && \
rm /tmp/java-installer.properties
ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/java-certified-11-jdk/bin \
    JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/java-certified-11-jdk \
    java_JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:+UseContainerSupport"
```

Shell logic inside the container:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
TARGET_JDK=JAVA8
if [ $TARGET_JDK == JAVA8 ]; then
   JAVA_PATH="/opt/xxx/java"
   echo "${JAVA_PATH}"
   export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_PATH}/bin
   export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_PATH}
   export xxx_JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:+UseContainerSupport"
else
   JAVA_PATH="/opt/xxx/xxx-yyy-certified-11-jdk"
   echo "${JAVA_PATH}"
   export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_PATH}/bin
   export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_PATH}
   export xxx_JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:+UseContainerSupport"
fi
```

Comment: To improve readability and the possibility of getting your question answered quickly, you should edit your question to remove the heading font from your opening paragraph. Additionally, place all your code within code blocks for better formatting and syntax highlighting.

Comment: Add the version of java you want used to the beginning of the PATH (or remove the version you don't want used from the PATH)

Answer (score 2):

When you run your application, it will only use one JRE or the other.  There's not a need to have the unused JRE in the image.

You can use a Dockerfile [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) to specify what JRE the *image* should be built with.  This appears to `RUN` commands as a normal environment variable.  This is helped by most of your installation logic being the same across both JRE versions.

The first thing I might write is a standalone shell script to do the installation.  This will be a little easier to edit in your favorite IDE, and to test outside the container.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = 8 ]; then
  JAVA_VERSION=8.0.6.35
  JAVA_ARCHIVE_NAME=java-sdk-8.0-6.35-x86_64-archive.bin
elsif [ "$1" = 11 ]; then
  JAVA_VERSION=11.0.12.0
  JAVA_ARCHIVE_NAME=java-certified-jdk_x64_linux_11.0.12.0.bin
else
  echo >&2 <<EOF
Usage: install-java.sh [8|11]
EOF
  exit 1
fi

curl {java-resource}/cloud/runtimes/java/${JAVA_VERSION}/linux/x86_64/${JAVA_ARCHIVE_NAME} -o /tmp/java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin
chmod +x /tmp/java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin

cat >/tmp/java-installer.properties <<EOF
INSTALLER_UI=silent
LICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE
USER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/java
EOF

/tmp/java-java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin -i silent -f /tmp/java-installer.properties
rm /tmp/java-java-sdk-${JAVA_VERSION}.bin
rm /tmp/java-installer.properties
```

Then in the Dockerfile, you need to set an `ARG` to accept the version setting, `COPY` in the script, and `RUN` it.

```sh
COPY install-java.sh ./
ARG java_version=11
RUN ./install-java.sh ${java_version}
ENV PATH=/opt/java/bin:$PATH
```

Now you can build and run your container as normal, and it will *only* contain Java 11

```sh
docker build -t myapp-java11 .
docker run --rm myapp-java11 java -version
docker run myapp-java11
```

But you can also build an alternate image built on Java 8

```sh
docker build --build-arg java_version=8 myapp-java8 .
docker run --rm myapp-java8 java -version
docker run myapp-java8
```

This saves you the trouble of trying to figure out the installation path at startup time, and gives you a smaller image that doesn't contain an entire JRE you're not using.

The one thing this setup doesn't do is add the `+XX:ContainerSupport` setting, but it shouldn't be necessary on recent builds of even the older Java 8.  Conditionally setting an `ENV` is hard, but you could do it in an entrypoint wrapper script based on what `java -version` returns.